Emded Youtube iframe unable to set white background
I have added the YouTube video to the Product gallery and currently, It comes with a black background. I want to set a white background instead of black.
I have tried with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810861/change-the-background-colour-of-youtube-video-embed solution but not work.
For more references please check the following screenshot:

Please help on this
